# Docker pull private registery first and docker hub if not found image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I try to find a solution with **docker pull** to pull my image from my private registry first,and then docker hub if not found in my private registry.

Currently i can pull like this if i want to go to my private registry: `docker pull @hostname_private_registery/@image_name`

i don't want to use **@hostname_private_registery** in the command, because i already i will have a big trouble with the dev.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, the `from` command does not include a fallback on fail option. You could, however, check the availability of your private registry beforehand in some kind of script, then use string replaces on your dockerfile ARG values to chose your respective active registry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following shell script to achieve this.

```
if docker pull @hostname_private_registery/@image_name ; then
    echo "Image pulled from local registry"
else
    docker pull @image_repo/@image_name
    echo "Image pulled from DockerHub"
fi
```

You can replace the echo with whatever you need to do after the pull.